# extracting from dataset based on value

Tags: r

I am bit of newbie in R. If I have a dataset and I would like to extract based on a value in dataset:

```
data<- read.csv(...)

data
   name date id
1
2
3
4
```

If I would just like to filter this data based on a value in date say date = "05/31/2000".
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
data[data$date == as.Date("05/31/2000"),]   ,
```

assuming that `data$date` is a `Date`.